# Как сделать кнопку (фигуру) на CSS?

Tags: css3

Здравствуйте, нужен код css3 для создания таких фигур как на скрине
заранее спасибо[image: ![фигуры>>]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggDZ.jpg)

Comment: [Гугл](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B) вам в помощь ...http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 4em;
}

.a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3em solid green;
}

.b:before, .b:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  border-left: 1.5em solid transparent;
}

.b:before {
  top: 0;
  border-top: 1.5em solid blue;
}

.b:after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid green;
}

.r { /* I need the 3rd element*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 1.5em solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1.5em solid transparent;
  border-top: 1.5em solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<p class=a></p>
<p class=b><span class=r></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
svg {
  width: 10em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 1em;
  overflow: visible;
}

path {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 1;
  fill: silver;
}
```

```html
<svg width=100 height=30>
  <path d="M .5 .5 h 99.5 l 47 47 h -146.5 z" />
</svg>

<svg width=100 height=30>
  <path d="M .5 .5 h 99.5 l 23.5 23.5 l -23.5 23.5 h -99.5 l 23.5 -23.5 z" />
</svg>
```